# Frame on $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$

Tags: differential-geometry

I worked out the simplest example concerning concepts like development/anti-development, however, I still have some concerns and lack a bit of intuition. Let me first walk you through my example:

Let $M = \mathbb{R}$ with a general connection given by $\nabla_e e = \Gamma e$, where $e$ is the usual unit vector in $\mathbb{R}$. In other words, for a differentiable function $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$, $e(f)= f^{\prime}$ "The derivative of $f$ in the direction $e$". Consider a curve "Line" $x_t = t$, let $u_0 e= e \partial_e$ be the initial frame. To describe a frame $u$, we need to specify $u_t$ $\mapsto$ $(x_{t}^i,u_{t}^i)$ the point $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and the basis vector $u \partial_e$. Under this choice of coordinates $u_0 \mapsto (0,1)$, the condition that the frame is a parallel frame can be seen from $$
    0 = \nabla_{\partial_e} u^i_t \partial_e = u^i_t \Gamma(t)+ \dot{u}^i_t \iff \dot{u}^i_t = -\Gamma(t)u^i_t$$
The frame $u_t$ is therefore described by $\Biggl(\displaystyle x_t, $$ \displaystyle e^{-\displaystyle \int_{0}^t \Gamma(s)ds}$$\Biggl)$ and the anti-development $w_t$ is defined as $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{t} e^{\displaystyle \int_{0}^{s} \Gamma(\nu)d\nu }ds$

- Shouldn´t the gammas vanish, since we are in a flat space "$\mathbb{R}$"?
- How should I think of the coordinates of this frame $\Biggl(\displaystyle x_t, $$ \displaystyle e^{-\displaystyle \int_{0}^t \Gamma(s)ds}$$\Biggl)$ in $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$

Thanks a lot!

Comment: There is no curvature on a $1$-dimensional manifold, so — independent of the connection — this space will be flat. However, connection forms certainly do not need to vanish. Even for the Levi-Civita connection on the plane, look at what happens in polar coordinates.

Comment: Thanks! I missed out that example.

Comment: @TedShifrin can you come up with any intuition on how to think about a frame with this exponential expression? Ofc it comes from the fact that the Frame should obey the equation of parallel transport along the line $t$ but I get my head around this and try to connect this expression with the fact that these frames specify all possible orientations on the frame bundle $\mathcal{F}(\mathbb{R})$

Comment: You're just asking for a (stretching) function $\lambda$ so that the covariant derivative of $\lambda(x)e(x)$ will be $0$. That is, as $e(x)$ increases in length, $\lambda$ must be $<1$, etc. We get $\lambda' e + \lambda e' =( \lambda' + \Gamma\lambda)e = 0$, so $\lambda'/\lambda = -\Gamma$.  ... I prefer to see this in the context of a surface, where you can clearly visualize the rotation of a frame. See the discussion of parallel translation on a sphere on pp. 68-71 of my differential geometry text, freely available at the link in my profile.